# Make background image the size of screen

Tags: html, css, background-image

I want the background image to fill the screen and am not worried about losing aspect ratio. Have trued everything, don't think I'm missing anything obvious...

The HTML:

```css
.phone {
  margin: auto;
  height: 737px;
  width: 654px;
  background-image: url("/imgs/phone.png");
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 536px;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
}

iframe {
  width: 350px;
  /* adjust to your needs */
  max-width: 100%;
  /* to make it responsive */
}

body {
  background-image: url("/imgs/CV.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

The CSS:
```

```html
  body {
    background-color: #93B874;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div className="phone" style="margin:auto; height: 630px;width: 558px; background-image:url(/imgs/phone.png); top:50%; left:50%;">
    <div className="container">
      <iframe style="height: 458.18px; width: 290px; margin: auto; position: relative; top: 85px; left: 132px;" src="http://foodsharing-production.herokuapp.com"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Preview:
http://soupedupkitchencom.fatcow.com/CV/CV.html

Comment: Please use SO Snippet to format your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `background-size: cover` to the rule for `body`

Or if you  want to make sure the whole background-image is shown and really don't care about a distorted image, you can use `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Here's a snippet with your code. If you change back the background-size of `body` to `auto` (as you had it) , you see the original size of the placeholder image

```css
.phone {
  margin: auto;
  height: 737px;
  width: 654px;
  background-image: url("/imgs/phone.png");
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 536px;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
}

iframe {
  width: 350px;
  /* adjust to your needs */
  max-width: 100%;
  /* to make it responsive */
}

body {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200x150/fa0?text=this is an image");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

The CSS:
```

```html
<body>
  <div className="phone" style="margin:auto; height: 630px;width: 558px; background-image:url(/imgs/phone.png); top:50%; left:50%;">
    <div className="container">
      <iframe style="height: 458.18px; width: 290px; margin: auto; position: relative; top: 85px; left: 132px;" src="http://foodsharing-production.herokuapp.com"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```